# Solving a polynomial with a natural log included with other terms for zero

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, graphing-functions

This problem has been plaguing me. Can the following equation be solved for zero? When I graph it, it clearly has solutions, but I'm struggling to solve on paper.

[(x-5)^2] - ln(x) = 0

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "solve for zero", but I don't think the equation can be solved for $x$ if that's what you intend (at least with any elementary functions or even special functions WA tried). You could get a solution in terms of a series expansion if you desire.

Comment: Yes I meant solve for x sorry- I guess I was trying to say solve for x when set equal to zero

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not solvable in terms of elementary functions or Lambert W. You need to solve your equation numerically.

You need the term [closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

$$(x-5)^2-\ln(x)=0$$
$$(x-5)^2=\ln(x).$$
We see, your equation cannot have a solution that is an [algebraic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) because for algebraic $x$, the left-hand side of the latter equation is an algebraic number whereas the right-hand side is a transcendental number.

$x\to e^t$, for all real $t$:
$$(e^t)^2-10e^t-t+25=0$$
The function on the left-hand side of this equation is an algebraic function in dependence of both $t$ and $e^t$. Liouville proved that such kind of functions (over a complex domain without isolated points) don't have [(partial) inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that are [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

The equation is also an algebraic equation in dependence of both $t$ and $e^t$. Lin proved, assuming [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true, that such kind of equations don't have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$\frac{1}{5+\sqrt{t}}\ e^t=1$$

We see, the equation is not solvable in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and poosibly not in terms of generalized Lambert W.